# Error in angular 12 using NgbOffcanvas from ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular12

I add ng-bootstrap to my app using ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

I added the NgbModule and when I try to use for example NgbActiveOffcanvas or NgbOffcanvas apperas that error on the import

Module '"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"' has no exported member 'NgbOffcanvas'

```
import { NgbActiveOffcanvas, NgbOffcanvas } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

????

Comment: [OffCanvas](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/offcanvas/api) is from ng-bootstrap 12.1.0, if you has Angular 12 you're using ng-bootstrap 10.0.0, see [getting starting](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#dependencies) to know the related ng-bootstrap version and Angular version

Comment: I know that I'm using ng-bootstrap 10 with Angular 12, the problem is that i have an error when try to import offcanvas import { NgbActiveOffcanvas, NgbOffcanvas } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

Comment: the versión of ng-bootstrap 10 **NOT** have implemented OffCanvas, only ng-bootstrap 12.1.0, so if you don't upgrade the ng-bootstrap -but also you need upgrade to Angular 13 or above- you can **not** use the component